# For loop changing the passed down array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have the following code to do some operation on an array, in this case, `[[1,2],[3,4]]`:

```
export default function App() {
  const a = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
  ];
  console.log(a, "- the array a in App");
  const b = M(a);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Magic with loops.</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function M(input) {
  console.log(input, "-- input inside M");

  const rows = input.length;
  const columns = input[0].length;

  /*for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      input[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }*/

  console.log(input, "-- input after for loop");

  return input;
}
```

With the for loop commented out in the function M, I see the array `[[1,2],[3,4]]` logged out on the console. But when I uncomment the for loop, all I see is `[[0,0],[0,0]]` for all of the places that I'm logging the array.

To me, it looks as if the for loop loops over the array before any of the logging happens to the console. Is this what's happening? If not, why does it log out `[[0,0],[0,0]]` before even the for loop starts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because its pass by reference and when you change input you change a array